# Android. RecyclerView . onClickLisenet not work correct

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I used android RecyclerView.Adapter. i can not manage my onClickListener.When I do click on item worked and this ithem and another item
When I set my itemView

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
```

and when  do click 'GONE' works to two items.
see in photo
[image: it is first image when I do not do click]

[image: it is second image when I do click and worked my 'GONE']

[image: but 'GONE' worked to another item]

**this my adapter.**

```
public class WordAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WordAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<LessonListActivity.Words> words;


public WordAdapter(List<LessonListActivity.Words> words) {
    this.words = words;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_content, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final LessonListActivity.Words myListData = words.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(words.get(position).getEN());


}

@Override
public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
    super.setHasStableIds(hasStableIds);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return words.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.word);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

what can i do to make them work only if we click them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one list to save all selected indexes and use it in onBindViewHolder to manage visibility of views.

Add index to be removed in list by clicking on view.

```
 public class WordAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WordAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private List<LessonListActivity.Words> words;
        ArrayList<Integer> listSelected = new ArrayList<>();
    
        public WordAdapter(List<Words> words) {
            this.words = words;
        }
    
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_content, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);
            return viewHolder;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final LessonListActivity.Words myListData = words.get(position);
            holder.textView.setText(words.get(position).getEN());
    
            if (listSelected.contains(position)) {
                //Here view will be invisible it will show white space. you can set height 0 to remove white space.
                holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
            super.setHasStableIds(hasStableIds);
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return words.size();
        }
    
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView textView;
            public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    
    
            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                this.textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.word);
                relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (!listSelected.contains(getLayoutPosition())) {
                            listSelected.add(getLayoutPosition());
                        }
                        notifyItemChanged(getLayoutPosition());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```